# EF Linq query with join, group and sum

Tags: entity-framework, linq, inner-join, aggregate-functions

Trying to construct a LINQ query that performs a simple inner join, groups the data and sums two of the columns. From the examples I've seen it looks fairly straightforward but I must have missed something along the way.

```
public class Employee
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Name { get; set; }
}

public class Inventory
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
  public decimal OffSite { get; set; }
  public decimal OnSite { get; set; }
}

public class InventoryTotal
{
  public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
  public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
  public decimal EmployeeOffSite { get; set; }
  public decimal EmployeeOnSite { get; set; }
}
```

The query I have created looks like this

```
var result = from a in db.Inventory                            
             join b in db.Employee on a.EmployeeId equals b.Id
             group new { a, b } by a.EmployeeId into c                            
             select new InventoryTotal
             {
               EmployeeId = c.Key,
               EmployeeName = c.Name,
               EmployeeOffSite = c.Sum(d => d.a.OffSite),
               EmployeeOnSite = c.Sum(d => d.a.OnSite)
             };
```

One issue appears to be with the **Name** column, the only value I want to obtain from the join with Employee. I would like to understand how to properly access that column and better understand how to construct this query as a whole.

*EmployeeName = c.Name* is not valid, nor are a few other combination I've tried.

Comment: Ultimately SQL gets generated for your LINQ query and SQL will not allow / does not understand how to include columns in the result that are NOT either part of the GROUP BY or an Aggregate like SUM.  I assume that this is underlying reason for the complaint from LINQ or VS.  As odd as this suggestion may seem trying adding a MAX() aggregation function to the output column `EmployeeName` like this: `EmployeeName = c.Max( c.Name ),`  Does that change get it to compile and run?

Comment: You shouldn't join. Use a navigation property for the relationship between Employee and Inventory. Then you don't need this grouping at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two tables: `Employees` and `Inventories`. There is a one-to-many relation between these two: Every Employee has zero or more Inventories; every Inventory is the Inventory of exactly one Employee, namely the Employee that the foreign key EmployeeId refers to.

**Requirement:** from every Employee get his Id and Name, and the total of all his OffSite and OnSite inventories.

Since you are using entity framework, there are three methods to do this. One is to do the (Group-)Join yourself, the other is to let entity framework do the (Group-)Join, and finally, the most intuitive part is to use the `virtual ICollection<Inventory`.

### Do the GroupJoin yourself

Whenever you have a one-to-many relation, like Schools with their Students, Customers with their Orders, or Employees with their Inventories, and you want to start at the "one" side, consider to use one of the overloads of [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin).

On the other hand, if you want to start on the "Many" side, if you want the Student with the School he attends, the Order with the Customer who placed the order, consider to use [Queryable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.join)

You want to fetch "Employees with (some information about) their Inventories, so we'll use a GroupJoin. I'll use the overload of GroupJoin with a parameter resultSelector, so we can specify what we want as result.

```
var inventoryTotals = dbContext.Employees.GroupJoin(dbContext.Inventories,

employee => employee.Id,            // from every Employee take the primary key
inventory => inventory.EmployeeId,  // from every Inventory take the foreign key

// parameter resultSelector: from every Employee, and all Inventories that have a foreign
// key that refers to this Employee, make one new
(employee, inventoriesOfThisEmployee) => new InventoryTotal
{
    EmployeeId = employee.Id,
    EmployeeName = employee.Name,

    EmployeeOffSite = inventoriesOfThisEmployee
        .Select(inventory => inventory.OffSite).Sum(),
    EmployeeOnSite = inventoriesOfThisEmployee
        .Select(inventory => inventory.OnSite).Sum(),
});
```

### Let Entity Framework do the GroupJoin

This one feels a bit more natural, for every Employee we Select one InventoryTotal, as requested.

```
var inventoryTotals = dbContext.Employees.Select(employee => new InventoryTotal
{
    // Select the Employee properties that you want.
    EmployeeId = employee.Id,
    EmployeeName = employee.Name,

    // Get the inventories of this Employee:
    EmployeeOffSite = dbContext.Inventories
        .Where(inventory => inventory.EmployeeId == employee.Id)
        .Select(inventory => inventory.OffSite).Sum(),

    EmployeeOnSite = dbContext.Inventories
        .Where(inventory => inventory.EmployeeId == employee.Id)
        .Select(inventory => inventory.OnSite).Sum(),
});
```

### Use the virtual ICollections

This one feels the most natural. It is also very easy to unit test your usage without a real database.

If you've followed the [entity framework conventions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), you will have classes similar to:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    ... // other properties

    // Every Employee has zero or more Inventories (one-to-many)
    public ICollection<Inventory> Inventories {get; set;}
}

public class Inventory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal OffSite { get; set; }
    public decimal OnSite { get; set; }
    ... // other properties

    // Every Inventory is the Inventory of exactly one Employee, using foreign key
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee {get; set;}  
}
```

This is enough for entity framework to detect the tables, the columns of the tables and the relations with the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...). Only if you want to deviate from the conventions: different identifiers for tables and columns, non-default column types etc Attributes or fluent API is needed.

> In Entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by the non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables.

The foreign key is a column in the table, hence it is non-virtual. The Inventory has no Employee column, hence property Employee is virtual.

Once you've defined the virtual ICollection, the query is simple:

**Requirement:** from every Employee get his Id and Name, and the total of all his OffSite and OnSite inventories.

```
var inventoryTotals = dbContext.Employees.Select(employee => new InventoryTotal
{
    // Select the Employee properties that you want.
    EmployeeId = employee.Id,
    EmployeeName = employee.Name,

    EmployeeOffSite = employee.Inventories
        .Select(inventory => inventory.OffSite).Sum(),

    EmployeeOnSite = employee.Inventories
        .Select(inventory => inventory.OnSite).Sum(),    
});
```

Simple comme bonjour!

Comment: I was approaching this backwards, from the Inventory perspective and not the Employee. You have answered my question but more importantly you've absolutely improved my understanding of the virtual collection properties in EF. Great explanation, it really is a easy as hello! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **Name** to grouping key:

```cs
var result = from a in db.Inventory                            
             join b in db.Employee on a.EmployeeId equals b.Id
             group a by new { a.EmployeeId, a.Name } into c                            
             select new InventoryTotal
             {
               EmployeeId = c.Key.EmployeeId,
               EmployeeName = c.Key.Name,
               EmployeeOffSite = c.Sum(d => d.OffSite),
               EmployeeOnSite = c.Sum(d => d.OnSite)
             };
```